# The same autocomplete works in one solution, but not in the other one

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I've tried everything and this is driving me mad.
I made an autocomplete which works in a solution, but when I export it (copy and paste) in my main solution it doesn't work anymore and I keep getting the following error: "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference".
It can't be the jquery version and stuff, cause it works in the other solution.

aspx:
CodiceFiscale.aspx

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/them/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />            
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#MainContent_provatxt").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var param = { cityName: $('#MainContent_provatxt').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "CodiceFiscale.aspx/GetCities",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
});
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="provatxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Ah btw yea, I have to get the elements by #MainContent_ since the id of the textbox in the browser is different than the one in the project, but it works fine in the other solution.

code behind: CodiceFiscale.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCities(string cityName)
    {

        List<string> City = new List<string>();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT nome_comune FROM comuni WHERE nome_comune LIKE '%{0}%'", cityName);
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Database=servizi; Uid=root; Pwd=root;"))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    City.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        return City;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control your client id with ClientIDMode to make ID more predictable ([post about that](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)).
What does server return in your `success` function?

Comment: I'm getting "param" is undefined.
And an exception in data: "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: so it seems that you have a wrong id in expression `$('#MainContent_provatxt').val()`. Could you verify the id with browser developer tools?

Comment: Where am I supposed to find it? I usually click on the textbox with the inspector, but in this case there's not a textbox

Comment: Ok It looks like this
    $('#MainContent_provatxt').val() is the problem, cause I can change it to everything and I get null value, but I don't know how to get the Id, it seems it's not displayed in the page

Comment: If the autocomplete initializes - than the id is right. Try to do `data: request.term` in your `source` function.

Comment: I tried data: request.term in my source function, I get the first 3 letters I type. edit: I always get the first 3 letters I type, also with a different string from #MainContent_provatxt.

It enters the function cause I get the error in the positive response when it says that my param string is null

Comment: Autocomplete sends first request after user types 3 characters by default. You can control it by `minLength` property. The `request.term` must contain all the text in text box in a corresponding request. From [jQuery UI doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source): _A request object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo"._

Comment: I used the debugger, it says that data is undefined, while param works. in the other solution this code works :/

Comment: Nothing to do.. it doesn't work for no reason.. I exported all the project in a new solution and it works now. I'm gonna give you the best answers, thanks for your time